# Wrong keyboard layout during disk encryption passphrase entry

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, luks, input-language

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
In GNOME I have two keyboard layouts english and russian while system wide language is set to english.
During OS installation I've set LUKS encription with a passphrase in english.
Did not have any issues until recently, my passphrase for disk encryption would not work anymore. Because you can't see what you type, it took me some time to realize that something is wrong with a layout. I have entered my passphrase using Alt codes and it worked(eg. Alt-110 Alt-117 refering to http://charmap.ru/alt_table.htm).
Somehow my input language has changed to russian by default for passphrase.
In addition, shortcuts for switching input language do not work as well (have tried all possible shortcuts)
How do I change it back to english?

Contents of /etc/default/keyboard:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us,ru

XKBVARIANT=,

BACKSPACE=guess
```

Comment: Have tried to change LUKS disk password using Disks utility. It accepted my passphrase in english and successfully changed it to a different one (also in english). After reboot I'm facing the same problem, new password is not working. The only way to get into the system is by using Alt codes. I will try making a new password in russian as a temporal fix, but would like to find a real solution. I'm guessing, that is initramfs issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard` outputs.

Comment: How exactly did you enter ALT codes?

Answer (score 8):

`echo "KEYMAP=Y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
update-initramfs -u`

Solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that you figured out a way.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install) this worked:

1. Change the `XKBLAYOUT` in `/etc/default/keyboard` to `XKBLAYOUT="us"` (assuming you want us layout).
2. run `sudo uptdate-initramfs -u`  (this updates the cached layout, among other things)