# Can’t change console keyboard

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, luks, 20.10

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.10. I installed it upon an encrypted LVM disk. At install time, I have chosen french bépo as my keyboard configuration (I think that the fact it is not qwerty is the only relevant information here).

At boot time (to uncrypt the disk) and in console (via ctrl+alt+f4 for instance), the keyboard is still in qwerty, which is really annoying. Anywhere else, the keyboard configuration is correct.

I have tried several things to solve this problem, such as running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout` but it doesn’t solve my problem. Moreover, my `/etc/default/keyboard` file is correct, even after rebooting :

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="tm2030USB-102"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="bepo_afnor"
XKBOPTIONS="compose:lwin"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

So, really I don’t get what’s wrong. I use GNU/Linux since 2005, bépo since 2014, and this is the very first time I encounter such a problem. The only new thing is it is the first time I use LUKS encryption, but I don’t know if it is relevant.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071878/wrong-keyboard-layout-during-disk-encryption-passphrase-entry  helpful?

Comment: I gave it a try, but as expected it didn’t work : the KEYMAP hook is Debian specific. Thanks anyway.