# Change keyboard layout for full disk encryption login

Tags: grub2, keyboard-layout, cryptsetup

My work recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a laptop of mine with full disk encryption using cryptsetup (I would have preferred to install it myself, but I wasn't given the choice...). The problem is that my laptop has a QWERTY keyboard, but they installed it with a French AZERTY keyboard for the disk encryption passphrase entry step. I have tried several things to change the keyboard to QWERTY, but I cannot get it to work. Initially, I changed the GRUB configuration to use `en_US` following the instructions here:

[How to change grub command-line (grub shell) keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout)

This seems to have worked, but if I understand correctly, encryption passphrase entry comes after GRUB, so this didn't fix my problem.

Next, I tried the instructions here:

[Wrong keyboard layout during disk encryption passphrase entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071878/wrong-keyboard-layout-during-disk-encryption-passphrase-entry)

This changed the keyboard that was displayed on the encryption passphrase entry screen to `us` (i.e., it shows a little keyboard icon with the letters `us` right next to it instead of `fr` as it was previously), but when I go to actually enter the passphrase the keyboard is still French/AZERTY. I suspect this is because the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071878/wrong-keyboard-layout-during-disk-encryption-passphrase-entry) are for an older version of Ubuntu and they only apply to the `initramfs` launch, but not whatever is used at the moment of encryption passphrase entry.

What is the appropriate way to change the keyboard layout for encryption passphrase entry? More generally, is there a way to assure that GRUB/cryptsetup/... all use the same QWERTY keyboard layout?

Comment: GRUB launches before the passphrase prompt appears (just to clear that point) ... However, my advice to handle such situation is from a live system where you can unencrypt, mount and `chroot` to your encrypted system to change the passphrase to something compatible with your keyboard's layout.

Comment: I wasn't sure if grub was first or second, thanks for the clarification. But the issue isn't with compatibility of the password with my keyboard, it is that the encryption passphrase entry dialog proposes a keyboard that is not the physical keyboard of the laptop and I have no way to modify that keyboard layout at boot. The instructions I indicated below managed to get it so that the (software-based) keyboard layout used by the passphrase entry dialog matched the physical keyboard of the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to have an expert explain to me the best way to fix this issue, but it seems like following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071878/wrong-keyboard-layout-during-disk-encryption-passphrase-entry) adding `KEYMAP=Y` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` fixed the problem. I had previously changed the keyboard to `us` in `/etc/default/keyboard` and updated `initramfs`, but this did not seem to be enough to fix the keyboard layout, you need to both modify `/etc/default/keyboard` and modify `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` before updating the `initramfs` (with `sudo update-initramfs -u`) to change the encryption password dialog keyboard.